# Earliest version of SQL Server with OPENJSON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, json

What is the earliest Microsoft SQL-Server version having the T-SQL `OPENJSON` function?

---

As far as I could see before asking this question, the Microsoft manual shows the function's documentation [for any version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2014). Interestingly, the version selector reverts to to SQL Server 2017, which could be indicative of something or nothing at all.

This other page mentions the same function but in relation to a [SQL Server 2016 demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?#learn-more-about-json-in-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database).

Answer (score 4):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) the `OPENJSON` command requires compatibility mode `130` - this is SQL Server 2016

In this case this means that the feature was introduced in SQL Server 2016, and can only be used in databases where the Compatibility model is set to 130 (SQL Server 2016) or higher.

Compatibility levels are tied to a specific SQL Server version and are listed at [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level).